# Weird date format from mysql in vuejs

Tags: mysql, vue.js, date

Time in mysql is stored like this

```
2022-04-25 11:03:20
```

but when it is showed on client with vuejs i am getting this as response

```
2022-04-25T09:03:20.000Z
```

How do i show it as it is shown in db?

Comment: That's in ISO format. If you do `new Date('2022-04-25T09:03:20.000Z')` (with the returned date as the parameter), you'll have a JavaScript date object, that you can display however you like.

Comment: *How do i how it as it is shown in db?* Simply convert the output column from datetime to string datatype. I.e. not `SELECT ... , datetime_column, ...` but `SELECT ... , CAST(datetime_column AS CHAR), ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date you're getting is in [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You'll want to continue to store it like that so you've got the timezone (as denoted by the suffix 'Z'). In your frontend, it's easy to convert the date into any format you like.

For example, based on your example, you can use:

```js
const dateFromDb = '2022-04-25T09:03:20.000Z';

const dateForUi = new Date(dateFromDb).toLocaleString('nl-NL');

console.log(dateForUi); // 25-4-2022 10:03:20
```

You can also convert any date object back into ISO format, using [`.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

There's also many other date formatting methods (outlined in the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) docs), or for more advanced date / time operations there are libraries like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)